# How to properly use Task object in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an ASP .NET MVC 5 application that requires me to use the Task objects that were introduced in .NET 4.0. I am browsing through a few links that give an overview of Task objects. However, I could use a bit of help to check if I am going in the right direction.

Here is the stub that is generated by Visual Studio:

```
public Task<MyAppUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName) {
   throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

I have written a method called mySearch() that searches through a list. I could use this function for my implementation:

```
public Task<MyAppUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName) {
  MyAppUser val = mySearch(userName);
  return Task<MyAppUser>.FromResult<MyAppUser>(val);
}
```

While this may work, I am thinking I am not really utilizing the Task paradigm properly. Perhaps I can write the code as follows:

```
public Task<MyAppUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName) {
  return Task<MyAppUser>.Factory.StartNew(() => mySearch(userName));
}
```

As I understand, I am simply returning a delegate as a Task object which the ASP.NET engine will execute as needed.

Am I using the Task paradigm correctly?

Comment: We use Task.Run(_ => ...)

Answer (score 2):

Don't ever return a new `Task` from an `XXXAsync` method - that's almost the worst thing you can do. In your case, using `Task.FromResult` is probably the best option (if you are indeed forced to use the `XXXAsync` methods and if you **really** don't have asynchronous I/O for the search method). In a web application, it's better to do the whole thing synchronously rather than appearing asynchronous while still taking up a different thread.

The reasoning is simple - asynchronous methods are a great way to conserve resources. Asynchronous I/O doesn't require a thread, so you can afford to reuse the current thread for other work until the data is actually ready. In ASP.NET, the callback will be posted back to a `ThreadPool` thread, so you've managed to increase your throughput essentially for free.

If you *fake* the asynchronous method by using `Task.FromResult`, it's true that this is lost. However, unlike in WinForms or WPF, you're not freezing the GUI, so there's no point in masking the lacking asynchronicity by spawning a new thread.

When you do the faking by using `TaskFactory.StartNew` or `Task.Run`, you're only making things worse, essentially - it's true that you release the original thread as with proper async I/O, but you also claim a new thread from the `ThreadPool` - so you're still blocking one thread, you just added a bunch of extra work for the plumbing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have a subsequent question but I will start another post for it.

Answer (score 2):

@Luaan's answer is quite good. I just want to expound on a couple of principles for using `async` on ASP.NET.

1) Use synchronous method signatures for synchronous work.

I'm not sure why VS is generating an *asynchronous* stub. Since your `mySearch` just "searches through a list" (a synchronous operation), then your method should look like this instead:

```
public MyAppUser FindByName(string userName) {
  return mySearch(userName);
}
```

2) Use `async`/`await` for asynchronous work (i.e., anything doing I/O). Do **not** use `Task.Run` or (even *worse*) `Task.Factory.StartNew` to fake asynchronous work within a request context.

For example, if you needed to search *in a database* (I/O), then that would be naturally asynchronous, and you should use the asynchronous APIs (e.g., EF6 has asynchronous queries):

```
public Task<MyAppUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName) {
  return dbContext.Users.Where(x => x.Name == userName).FirstAsync();
}
```

If you're *planning* to have asynchronous APIs but for now you're just doing test/stub code, then you should use `FromResult`:

```
public Task<MyAppUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName) {
  return Task.FromResult(mySearch(userName));
}
```